# Ghost templating with handlebars: posts with same tags

Tags: handlebars.js, ghost-blog

I'm creating a Ghost template using handlebarsjs. On the post.hbs page (blog post view) I'm looking for a solution to include other blog titles that have the same tags at the bottom of the post.hbs template. (Kinda like how on a Wordpress site you'll see similar articles listed at the bottom of a blog article page.)

Here's what I have so far:

```
{{#foreach tags}}
   {{#foreach posts}}
       <p>{{{title}}}</p>
   {{/foreach}}
{{/foreach}}
```

Is there a way to set variables and filter conditionals?

```
var current-tag = tag.name
foreach(posts as post)
   if(post.tag == current-tag)
      <p>{{post.title}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not something that is possible with the current version of Ghost. For a start the individual post.hbs pages are not passed the full list of posts, but rather the specific post for that page. This would require a custom handlebars helper which again, is not yet supported in Ghost.

I haven't delved deeply into the API, but I'd imagine this is something you would be able to do in the next release once Apps are available. See the [Ghost Roadmap](https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/wiki/Roadmap) for more details.

Also note that tag pages are scheduled to be released in the next week or so as part of 0.4.2. [#2111](https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/issues/2111). While not exactly what you're looking for, this is along the same lines and may help you.

Comment: Yeah, Ghost is interesting but I'm afraid that by the time it has everything I want, there'll be better alternatives. For this project I just ended up writing my own frontend angularjs app with a Firebase backend.